# Power BI Data Limits for Corporate Developer

Tags: powerbi

Do the 1GB/10GB limits apply to a corporate developer who is creating applications for a variety of groups in the organization?

For example, I may create 20 different applications for various departments as a developer.  Clearly I could exceed my personal limit, while each individual user may be lower than their personal limits.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a question of policy, not programming. Ask the company what their policies are.

Comment: @BilltheLizard I disagree. This is a Power BI Service limit and a relevant question. It's not s company policy.

Answer (score 0):

Yes the workspace limits apply to you too.

I would recommend you create several [group workspaces](http://www.sqlchick.com/entries/2015/9/20/groups-in-power-bi-how-sharing-and-security-works) instead of putting everything in your My Workspace. Each group has its own size limits separate from your My Workspace.